# Error creando un Identity en Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, sql

Que tal gente, espero que me puedan ayudar a resolver este problema aunque sea algo tonto, estoy intentando crear una tabla con un ID del tipo Identity y estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
Error que empieza en la línea: 1 del comando :
CREATE TABLE USUARIO (
userID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 100 INCREMENT BY 1),
username VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
pass VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
nickname VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
userType CHAR(5) CONSTRAINT CH_userType CHECK(userType IN ('comun', 'boss')),
CONSTRAINT PK_usuario
  PRIMARY KEY (userID)
);
Informe de error -
ORA-02000: missing ( keyword
02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"
```

Al parecer me falta un "(" pero no logro ver en donde, todo parece estar en orden, espero que puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Comment: No veo ningún problema con la sentencia. ¿Qué versión de Oracle usas? ¿Qué programa cliente usas para ejecutar la sentencia?

Comment: Estoy utilizando la version 11g con Oracle SQL Developer, yo tampoco veo ningún problema en ella pero aún así me da ese error :/

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a la versión de Oracle que usas. La habilidad de definir una columna como un `IDENTITY` es nuevo con la versión 12.

En las versiones anteriores, lo mejor que puedes hacer para aproximar la funcionalidad es definir un `SEQUENCE` que usas para asignar a la columna por medio de un trigger.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
create sequence usuario_seq START WITH 100 INCREMENT BY 1;
/

CREATE TABLE USUARIO (
userID NUMBER,
username VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
pass VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
nickname VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
userType CHAR(5) CONSTRAINT CH_userType CHECK(userType IN ('comun', 'boss')),
CONSTRAINT PK_usuario
  PRIMARY KEY (userID)
);
/

create trigger usuario_trigger
before insert on usuario
for each row
begin
  :new.userID := usuario_seq.nextval;
end;
/
```

**Referencias:**

- [On Oracle Database 12c, Part 1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-sep/o53asktom-1999186.html)
- [Identity Columns in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1)

Comment: Excelente amigo, gracias por la solución!